# php Fonts are bigger then expected when users enters special chars in the form

Tags: php, html, yii

When user enters `</`

in my form, all html markup gets broken. I'm using Yii framework..

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
```

How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clean / sanitize the input. This is for Yii: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/input/

```
$clean=Yii::app()->input->purify($string);
```

There's more examples in that link.

Answer (score 0):

I assume all markup is broken when you echo the data back out whether it's a field's value attribute or just on the page itself?

I give you:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php
- or http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

The problem is somebody is entering characters that when echo'd, look "like" actual HTML tags. You need to escape (typically *all*) user input as you output it anywhere on a page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's an escaping problem.
I don't know Yii framework, but try enclosing your value within htmlspecialchars. Eg:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($form->labelEx($model,'name')); ?>
```

Comment: now I see [_italic_] <label for="Place_name" class="required">Name <span class="required">*</span></label> as text, but fonts are still big